# Threestate checkbox inital binding Windows Store App / RT

Tags: wpf, checkbox, windows-store-apps, windows-rt

my checkbox doesn't bind the initial value correctly on startup:

```
<CheckBox IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{Binding StartWithSettings,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The checkbox is displayed empty on startup, but should be nulled (the box with the black square in it).

Getter is properly raised with null on startup, what am I missing?

## EDIT:

Below you can find my viewmodel, model code and a button to switch all three states of the checkbox. the strange thing happens when switching between null state and false state -> it always shows the false checkbox, whether its null or false, but the underlying data is correct.

do i toggle the checkboxstate directly by clicking the checkbox itself, all three states are displayed correctly.

It is a windows 8.1 store app, maybe the wpf checkbox control is another than the "usual" wpf checkbox and has a bug?

### viewmodel snippet:

```
public bool? StartWithSettings
{
    get
    {
        return _configurationModel.MyAppModel.StartWithSettings;
    }
    set
    {
        _configurationModel.MyAppModel.StartWithSettings = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("StartWithSettings");
    }
}
```

### model snippet

```
public class MyAppModel
{
    public bool? StartWithSettings { get; set; }

    public MyAppModel()
    {
        this.StartWithSettings = null;
    }
}
```

### snippet test code

```
private void ChangeCheckboxState()
{
    if (StartWithSettings == null)
    {
        StartWithSettings = true;
        return;
    }
    else if (StartWithSettings == true)
    {
        StartWithSettings = false;
        return;
    }
    else
        StartWithSettings = null;

}
```

Comment: What's the type of `StartWithSettings`? Is it `bool` or `bool?`? It will take value from your property and if it's not nullable, and you don't set it, then by default if will be false

Comment: its bool? in the model and in the viewmodel

Comment: when i test the model for its value, it has null as it should be, but the presentation doesn't fit its value

Comment: Did you confirm that binding works? If you check/uncheck it does it update view model? Some binding errors in output window?

Comment: yes, the binding works fine.

Comment: strange thing: do I initialize the control without the binding with IsChecked="{x:Null}", the designer displays the checkbox correctly in the 'null'-state. After starting the application, the box is again in the 'false'-state

Comment: Is there nothing in code that would affect state of that `CheckBox`?

Comment: no, absolute standard mvvm project in an early phase, no super fancy code in it ;)

Comment: binding with a normal binary checkbox works fine

Comment: i added some more information + code

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24070465/4905310

Answer (score 1):

The backing property that is bound to the property must be of type `bool?` in order to support **3 state check box**. Make sure that the backing field is set to null.

Also, you don't need to set `IsThreeState="True"`

**EDIT**: Since you mentioned Windows 8.1 and I assume this would be WinRT.

***Nullable types are not supported in WinRT/Win8 Dev.***

A solution would be [here](http://danrigby.com/2012/07/24/windows-8-dev-tip-nullable-dependency-properties-and-binding/)

Comment: I can assure that these conditions are met.

Comment: I have some trouble figuring out, how your tip could be integrated in my solution, since I don't use dependency properties. please could you explain more detailed how I can implement your solution?

Comment: @tronc You have to use dependency properties if you want ot achieve three state binding in Win8 dev.